# Matrices how to prove inverse = transpose = matrix when the matrix has a scalier

Tags: matrices

**Question 1**

Proof that the following is true for matrix $A$, $A^{(-1)}$ = $A^{T}$ = $A$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 6 \\
    1 & -6 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

In the question $A$ is scaled by $1/7$.

This part is straight forward $A^{t}$ = $A$

But when trying to proof that the $A^{(-1)}$ = $A$

The inverse is $A^2$

For example  $A^{(-1)}$

$a_{11}$ = $\frac{4}{49}$

$A$

$a_{11}$ = $\frac{2}{7}$

The only way I could proof this is By make $AA$ = $A^{(-1)}$

Comment: What? Clearly ${A'}\neq{A}$ in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is wrong, you have $A \neq A^T \neq A^{-1}$

Showing this:

you get $A^T$ by taking every row in $A$ and making in a column in a new matrix, so we get:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & -6 & 2 \\
    6 & 2 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Note: I didn't include the $\frac{1}{7}$ scalar here.

For a matrix to be equal to its transpose you need to have $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$

Now concerning its inverse, to find its inverse $B$ (usually denoted as $A^{-1}$) you need to solve the following $AB=I$, this should be pretty straightforward. Solving it we get:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    14/19 & 63/38 & 147/38 \\
    7/19 & -35/38 & 7/38 \\
    14/19 & -7/76 & -105/76 \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Note: This was solved while including the scalar, if I didn't do that then the result would be different.

We can conclude $A \neq A^T \neq A^{-1}$